# Ember global App variable

Tags: javascript, ember.js, ember-cli

I am developing my Ember as an addon
& inside my tests\dummy\app.js, I have

```
App = Ember.Application.extend({
  modulePrefix: config.modulePrefix,
});
```

My question is related to accessing global variable acrosss the Ember app.

Do I have to do

```
window.App = App;
```

in the above place only (i.e. where I'll have Ember.Application.extend())

OR can I do in some other place as well ?

Comment: You don't have to use global variables at all.

Comment: I need global variables. What is the alternative ?

Comment: It seems like you use `ember-cli`. There you load everything with ES6 Modules or with dependency injection. Not globales at all usually. Why do you think you need globales?

Comment: I need global variable to store POJO kind of information (so not exactly high level ones like route/controller classes, etc)...which I want to share across the app...i.e. that object info should be accessible in routes, controllers, services, etc

Comment: Then my answer should apply to your case. @testndtv

Comment: If you want to share pojo type information across your app, use a service to wrap it. That's what they are for :-)

Comment: yes, that is what i would like...any examples if you have with service?

Comment: You also may use the configuration. But for services checkout the [documentation](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.5.0/applications/services/)

Answer (score 1):

You can define a class in a js file such as:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

const MyClazz = Ember.Object.extend({
    // your properties and methods
});

const myObj = MyClazz.create({});
export default myObj;
```

This object will behave as a global object and you can access this object from anywhere you want like that:

```
import MyObj from '/...path';
...

MyObj.get('...');
```

Comment: Would it be necessary to use the the const keyword ?

Comment: I didn't test but **var** can be used.